# Proposal for badges on Beer, Wine & Spirits exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some of the exchanges have little quirks, for example: the badges on music exchange are musical notes...

I propose that the badges on our exchange look like little droplets of our various favorite beverages. For example: the bronze badge could look like a drop of whiskey, the gold badge; a foamy drop of beer. :)

Would it be pertinent to have a vote on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badge icons are part of a site's design.  All sites that are in beta, including this one, share a single design with generic badges.  When we reach a higher level of activity and can [graduate out of beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/162102), a Stack Exchange designer will give us our own custom design, including this element.  (It'll be the same grapheme in three different colors, not three different shapes.)

Comment: Do you know if the community has any input on the design when we do finally graduate? Where would one submit those requests? The main meta you linked? I wonder when BWSSE will be out of beta... My request would involve the single uniform shape of a drop of alcohol and then color would vary by badge as it already does... I suppose a glass or a bottle of colored liquid would work for the badge as well! I'm still fairly new to the SEs (just finding out about the metas, for example...)

Comment: @SuperQueryLad it'll be a while; we need to have a lot more activity first.  If you follow that link, you'll see that 10 questions per day is a baseline that SE considers; we're well below that.  (They do have to be quality questions, though; flooding the site with low-quality questions that just get closed wouldn't help.) . As for input, what I've seen on other sites is that the designer asks for input from the community when the time comes, and then shares a draft and collects feedback.  So yes, we'll have a chance to provide input, but not for a while.

Comment: I like the idea of the bottles - however we do need more questions - maybe we all need a proverbial kick.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposal for badges on alcohol exchange?**

Do not know how possible this is, but it is quite ingenious.

What I would like to see, is the following, but others may have another idea:

- Beer mug for bronze badges
- Wine glass for silver badges
- Shot glasses for gold badges

It may just make the site a little more interesting for others.

The [Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/badges) as already mentioned has three different badge symbols for it’s badges: Gold, Silver and Bronze.